# Kendo Ui Editor not sending FK on Create

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Using the Kendo Grid with popup Create.  Here is the code with datasource:

```
var PersId = $("#PersonId").val();
var ds_CommentsGrid = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: '@Url.Action("JsonGetComments", "TrespassOrder")/' + PersId,
            dataType: 'json',
        },
        update: {
            url: '@Url.Action("JsonEditComment", "TrespassOrder")',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST"
        },
        create: {
            url: '@Url.Action("JsonAddComment", "TrespassOrder")',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST"
            //contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
        },
        parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
            if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
            var values = {};
            values["CommentText"] = options.models[0].CommentText;
            values["ModifiedBy"] = options.models[0].ModifiedBy;
            values["ModifiedDate"] = options.models[0].ModifiedDate;
            values["CreatedBy"] = options.models[0].CreatedBy;
            values["CreatedDate"] = options.models[0].CreatedDate;
            values["PersonId"] = options.models[0].PersonId;
            return values;
        }
        }
    },
    batch: true,
    schema: {
        model: {
            id: "CommentId",
            fields: {
                CommentText: { editable: true },
                CreatedDate: { editable: false , type: "date"}, 
                ModifiedDate: { editable: false , type: "date" },
                CreatedBy: { editable: false },
                ModifiedBy: { editable: false },
                PersonId: { editable: false}
            }
        }
    },
    pageSize: 5
});

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#comment-list").kendoGrid({
        dataSource: ds_CommentsGrid,
        sortable: true,
        filterable: { extra: false, operators: {
            string: { startswith: "Starts with", eq: "Is equal to" }
        }
        },
        pageable: true,
        columns: [{
            field: "CommentText", title: "Comment", width: 300, filterable: true
        }, {
            field: "CreatedBy", title: "Author", filterable: false
        }, {
            field: "CreatedDate", title: "Original Date", format: "{0:g}", filterable: { ui: "datetimepicker" }
        }, {
            field: "ModifiedBy", title: "Edited By", filterable: false
        }, {
            field: "ModifiedDate", title: "Editted On", format: "{0:g}", filterable: { ui: "datetimepicker" }
            }, {
            command: ["edit"], title: "Actions"
        }],
        editable: "popup",
        toolbar: [{ name: "create", text: "Add New Comment" }]
    });
});
```

There are 2 problems:
1. The PersonId is not being sent with the Create.
2. The dates are being sent in a format that ends up getting to the MVC controller as null (1/1/0001).

Here is what is being sent to the controller:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:47621/TrespassOrder/JsonAddComment
Request Headersview source
Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Origin:http://localhost:47621
Referer:http://localhost:47621/Person/Detail/18
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.110 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
    CommentText:Blah blah, I am a comment.
    ModifiedBy:
    ModifiedDate:Fri Jun 14 2013 12:12:46 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
    CreatedBy:
    CreatedDate:Fri Jun 14 2013 12:12:46 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
    PersonId:
```

Notice the PersonId is empty.

Notice the commented-out contentType in the create, within the transport.  I tried using the json content type, but that returned an error saying that 'CommentText is an invalid JSON primitive".

So how do I format the dates so they show up in the controller, and how do I attach the foreign key (PersonId) to the data that is sent?

Comment: @OnaBai - Thanks I fixed the personid with:                     PersonId: { defaultValue: PersId }.  Any idea whats going on with the dates format?

Answer (score 1):

`PersonId` is set as not editable, it has not default value and there is no `column` definition. What do you expect to be sent on creation `PersId`? If so, you can `defaultValue` in the `schema.model.fields.PersonId` as `PersId`, something like:

```
schema   : {
    model: {
        id    : "CommentId",
        fields: {
            CommentText : { editable: true },
            CreatedDate : { editable: false, type: "date"},
            ModifiedDate: { editable: false, type: "date" },
            CreatedBy   : { editable: false },
            ModifiedBy  : { editable: false },
            PersonId    : { editable: false, defaultValue: PersId}
        }
    }
},
```

Regarding the format of the transmitted dates, they are transmitted as `strings` so you should convert them to a format that your controller is able to parse. For doing it, you should use `kendo.toString` (see this [article](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/globalization/dateformatting) about it). You might try using *Universal sortable date/time*, something like:

```
parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
        var values = {};
        values["CommentText"] = options.models[0].CommentText;
        values["ModifiedBy"] = options.models[0].ModifiedBy;
        values["ModifiedDate"] = kendo.toString(options.models[0].ModifiedDate, "u");
        values["CreatedBy"] = options.models[0].CreatedBy;
        values["CreatedDate"] = kendo.toString(options.models[0].CreatedDate, "u");
        values["PersonId"] = options.models[0].PersonId;
        return values;
    }
}
```